Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: Flutter project
I was able to build apps on xcode 15.4. There was requirement to use two version of xcode for multiple projects so I upgraded older xcode which was installed from app store to 16.0 and installed older version of xcode 15.4 from external source. After this build started failing for one of the project.
I am trying to run flutter project.
below is the error i am getting on archiving for arm64:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lsqlite3', '-lz'
ld: warning: search path '/Users/apple/Documents/proj/app/ios/Runner/AllSDK/paymentcontrolMini/libs' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Users/apple/Documents/proj/app/ios/Runner/AllSDK/SDPT' not found
ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/Users/apple/Documents/proj/app/ios/Pods/MLKitBarcodeScanning/Frameworks/MLKitBarcodeScanning.framework/MLKitBarcodeScanning', assuming: iOS
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBAuthorizeRequest", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBAuthorizeResponse", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBImageObject", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBMessageObject", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBSendMessageToWeiboRequest", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBSendMessageToWeiboResponse", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBWebpageObject", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WeiboSDK", referenced from:
       in weibo_kit[4](WeiboKitPlugin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

flutter doctor:
fvm flutter doctor --verbose                                         
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.19.6 on channel stable at /Users/apple/fvm/versions/3.19.6
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 54e66469a9 (8 months ago), 2024-04-17 13:08:03 -0700
    • Engine revision c4cd48e186
    • Dart version 3.3.4
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/apple/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/apple/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.11+0)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.16.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.102.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.139

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

